# Morph cut anything in Premiere

Tags: premiere, transitions

Instead of its key purpose, can I apply that effect (the effect we get when applied to a face) to other objects as well? If I can't do that with this method, is there an another way? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: No, and if you try the Adobe police will come and send you to prison. I shouldn't even be speaking to you, you're using an effect in an unapproved fashion, don't you know how much trouble you're in?

Comment: Seriously, tell us, what happened when you tried?

Comment: it takes forever to "Analyze in background"